# Installing drivers for old computer with windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I found my old laptop and I wanted to bring it back to life. After installing windows xp I started a search for drivers. I managed to find some of them but since it is really really old version of laptop (9-10 years old) I cannot find all of them. I tried to use some of software for managing drivers but I really don't want to pay like 20-30$ for it and also I can't find it online. Any suggestions how I could fix this?

Comment: Unless you have a device is not working most devices can work with the generic drive supplied by Microsoft.

Comment: Device is working but it can't be find from device manager when I try to update

Comment: Please specify the laptop model and the missing device drivers. Avoid using some random software, and always get drivers from the official manufacturer website whenever possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the specific device you are looking for driver in 'Device Manager'. Click the details tab, then scroll down to Hardware IDs. Should have VEN_XXXX (Vendor#) and DEV_XXXX (Device#). Punch those numbers into PCIDatabase.com and it should give you a link to either the manufacturers website or an OEM website that hosts compatible drivers, OR will tell you exactly what the device is to aid in your finding it.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Each vendor has 1 or 2 - 4 digit numbers to identify their hardware, and each device has a 4 digit number to identify it the specific device. That is what these numbers are.

EX Intel VEN_8086 - This is intels Vendor # and will appear in the device manager/registry on all their products.

EX VEN_8086 DEV_1228 - Intel Ethernet Adapter